# R language function arguments referencing data file

Tags: r, function

In the linear model function, one can write:

```
result <- lm(r ~ N, data = ds)
```

The function knows to look in dataframe ds for the variables r and N

I wrote a function called Check.Data.  The arguments ri and ni are variables in data file ds.

```
Check.Data(ri = ds$r, ni = ds$N, data = ds)  #This runs
Check.Data(ri = r, ni = N, data = ds)  #this does not
```

The second call to the function does not run because it can't find r:
Error in Check.Data(ri = r, ni = N, data = ds) : object 'r' not found

What commands do I need in the function so that it knows that the arguments for ri and ni are variables in ds without have to specify the data set (e.g., ri = ds$r, ni = ds$N)?

In case you want to look at the function, here it is:

```
Check.Data <- function(ri= ri, ni=ni, data = data)
  {

  #make sure values needed are non-missing
  if (missing(data))  stop("Function CheckData is terminated because data set name is missing.") 

  if (missing(ri))  stop("Function CheckData is terminated because ri is missing.") 

  if (missing(ni)) stop("Function CheckData is terminated because ni is missing.")  

  #add ri and ni to the data frame named data
  data$ri <- ri
  data$ni <- ni

  #make sure ri is numeric
  if(is.numeric(data$ri) == FALSE) stop("Function CheckData is terminated because ri is not numeric.") 

  #make sure ni is numeric
  if(is.numeric(data$ni) == FALSE) stop("Function CheckData is terminated because ni is not integer.") 


  #does ri have any missing data. if so issue message and stop
  if(any(ind.na <- is.na(data$ri))) stop(paste("ri has", sum(ind.na), "missing values. CheckData is terminated."))

  #does ni have any missing data. if so issue message and stop
  if(any(ind.na <- is.na(data$ni))) stop(paste("ni has", sum(ind.na), "missing values. CheckData is terminated."))

}
```

Comment: The "specific commands" will depend on what exactly you plan on doing with those variables. The technique you're describing is called non-standard evaluation, [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) is a good introduction. However, I would carefully consider whether the benefits of being able to specify `ri = r` instead of `ri = "r"` are worth the difficulty and complexity of implementing non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Ew, using `$` inside functions definitely not recommended. It's only a convenience function for use at the console level. Learn to use `[[` instead.

Answer (score 2):

R functions will generally attempt to evaluate their formal arguments in an environment where they called. Columns of objects are not first class objects in R, so unless there are vectors (or other data-objects) in the calling environment  with names `r` and `N`,  the second type of call will fail (unless you take special efforts). You are hoping that function will instead evaluate some of the arguments as symbols in the environment of the `data`. As joran points out this this is called NSE (non-standard evaluation.) One of the commonly used functions that does it is `library` or its close cousin `require`. You can see that the first operation in `require` is conversion of a symbol string to a character value. It can then be safely used to access column values with the `[`-function

```
myNSEfun <- function( ri = r, ni = N, data = ds){
                ri.col <- as.character(substitute(ri.col))
                ni.col <- as.character(substitute(ni.col))
                print( summary( data[ c(ri.col, ni.col) ] )) }
```